# Using ActionBarSherlock with Subversion

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, actionbarsherlock, subclipse

I´m developing an android-application and wants to implement the ActionBarSherlock at the same time syncing with Subversion. The ABS-library does not sync with SVN and when I installed the ABS-lib on another computer  no errors are shown except:
Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException   Unknown Android Packaging Problem

What I´m using:
Eclipse ADT Bundle Build:  v21.1.0-569685
Subclipse.
Latest ABS-package.

Followed ABS-installation instructions from 
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/

Is it possible to just copy the ABS-package into the projects own folder in order to enable syncing? Any solutions?

Grateful for answers!

Comment: Can you explain a tad more what you are trying to do? Why would you want to add ABS to SVN? It's an external library that is not really a part of your project - you just happen to use it. So why add it to the source control of your project?

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer Well ofcourse! I am trying to minimize the risk of errors that might appear when syncing the project to different computers. Currently the ABS-påackage is location linked to the project and when opening on another computer, adding ABS I get error NullPointerException before compiling... Ofcourse I will not compile with the whole ABS-package in project folder! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have these options:

1. Follow a defined folder structure within your company and enforce it. E.g. all external libs reside in /opt/libs and all working copies of projects reside in /opt/projects. Defined versions of the libs are on your companies servers and can be checked out. So your project would have a dependency to, say, ABS 4.3 and devs would have to checkout ABS as well as the project itself.
2. You set up your repository and include all dependencies within it. In this case a structure like this would be useful:

   ```
   /your-project
   /your-project/libs
   /your-project/libs/ABS
   /your-project/libs/some other library
   /your-project/your-android-project
   ```

   This way developers can not mix up. But you end up with a bloated structure.
3. Use Maven :-)

   A pain to set up - but probably the best solution currently.
4. Wait for the final release of Android's new build structure.

   If it's announced at Google IO 2013 (as of this writing that's one week to wait), you should use this option. But I doubt that it will be announced next week - so even though this probably would fix your woes, it's in all likelyhood no option at the moment.